# Which tables are using Change tracking

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My backup is failing: Failed to flush the commit table to disk in dbid 12 due to error 2601. Check the errorlog for more information.

my database has change tracking enabled. How can i determine which tables have it enables? i have looked at 50+ and can't locate the ones with it on. sql 2008 r2

Thanks

Comment: Might this be better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 33):

To find the tables that have Change Tracking enabled, execute the following script against the tracked database

```
SELECT s.name AS Schema_name, t.name AS Table_name 
FROM sys.change_tracking_tables ctt
JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON t.object_id = ctt.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
ORDER BY s.name, t.name
```

[image]

You can find more details about helpful system views for Change Tracking here:

[sys.change_tracking_tables (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895362.aspx)

[sys.change_tracking_databases (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934095.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a query by Brent Ozar that gives you a list of the Hidden Tables maintained by Change Tracking to store the changes, the tables involved in CT the rows and space taken up in those hidden tables.

[image]

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
GO

SELECT 
   sct1.name AS CT_schema,
   sot1.name AS CT_table,
   ps1.row_count AS CT_rows,
   ps1.reserved_page_count*8./1024. AS CT_reserved_MB,
   sct2.name AS tracked_schema,
   sot2.name AS tracked_name,
   ps2.row_count AS tracked_rows,
   ps2.reserved_page_count*8./1024. AS tracked_base_table_MB,
   change_tracking_min_valid_version(sot2.object_id) AS min_valid_version
FROM sys.internal_tables it
JOIN sys.objects sot1 ON it.object_id=sot1.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas AS sct1 ON sot1.schema_id=sct1.schema_id
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps1 ON it.object_id = ps1. object_id AND ps1.index_id in (0,1)
LEFT JOIN sys.objects sot2 ON it.parent_object_id=sot2.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS sct2 ON sot2.schema_id=sct2.schema_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps2 ON sot2.object_id = ps2. object_id AND ps2.index_id in (0,1)
WHERE it.internal_type IN (209, 210);
GO
```